# Bash Script: Decimal increments in loop (cannot do)

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I am trying to generate a bash script that generates input files automatically by changing the `celldm(1)`  variable from the previous input file by increasing +0.155 to it. How I solved this is by implementing a counter inside the loop to add 0.155 each time the loops run, and store that new value in the variable `newcelldm`. The problem is that bash is not accepting the float 0.155. Is there any way to solve this and still be able to add 0.155 into `newcelldm` ?

My code:

```
#!/bin/bash
count=7
template="x_1.in"

for val in {1..20..1}
do
    inp="x_${val}.in"
    pw.x < $inp &> ${inp%.*}.out
    count=$((count + 0.155))
    newcelldm="celldm(1) = ${count},"
    sed "s/^celldm(1) = .*/$newcelldm/" $template > $inp
done

awk '/unit-cell/{ecut=$4}
     /^!.*total/{print ecut, $5}' *out > etot_v_vol.dat
```

Comment: Bash doesn't do decimals, use for example `bc`: `count=1; echo 0.15+$count | bc`

Comment: Or `awk` which can also replace the `sed`: `awk -v v=$val '/^celldm(1) =/{$3=7+0.155*(v-1)} 1' $template >$inp`. Also I think you want to create the `$inp` file for each loop _before_ running `pw.x` on it. Do you really want to order the results as 1.out 10.out 11.out ... 19.out 2.out 20.out 3.out ... ?